# Does Warning C5029 Just Indicate a Microsoft Extension is being used?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

We're evaluating upgrading to VS2015, and getting warnings **C5029** when using __declspec(align(16)) in structure definitions.  This warning is apparently new with VS 2015, as we used the same code in VS 2013 without warnings.  The following is an example...

```
typedef __declspec(align(16)) struct tag_RECTF
{
    union
    {
        __m128 Rect;

        struct
        {
            float   left;
            float   top;
            float   right;
            float   bottom;
        };
    };

} RECTF;
```

The emitted warning is:

**C:\path\header.h(81): warning C5029: nonstandard extension used: alignment attributes in C++ apply to variables, data members and tag types only**

I've found that if I reverse the order of **__declspec(align(16))** and **struct** on the typedef line the warning is averted.  Trouble is, the Microsoft documentation suggests using the ordering I listed above (that causes the warning).

Near as I can tell the alignment IS being enforced with the ordering reversed, but I'd like to be sure this is the right workaround to avert the warnings.

There's woefully little info about C5029 online (nor even in the Microsoft documentation).

Do you have any advice / insight on this?

Thanks in advance.

-Noel

Comment: The warning is understandable as worded : alignment attributes do _not_ apply to `typedef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the warning is saying is that Standard C++ doesn't let you create a new type with a different alignment using `typedef`. In this case the warning is spurious, since you're using `__declspec(align())` your code doesn't conform to the C++ standard anyways.

Your example code is actually defining two types. The first type is `tag_RECTF` and has the default alignment. The second type is `RECTF` and has 16 byte alignment. When you swap `__declspec(align(16))` with `struct` you end up only only defining one type. In that case `RECTF` is just an alias for `tag_RECTF`, they're both the same type.

To put another way your example code is the equivalent of these two declarations:

```
 struct tag_RECTF {...};
 typedef __declspec(align(16)) tag_RECTF RECTF;
```

If you swap `__declspec` and `struct` then your example becomes the equivalent of the following:

```
 struct __declspec(aligned(16)) tag_RECTF {...};
 typedef tag_RECTF RECTF;
```

If you replace `__declspec(align(16))` with `alignas(16)` in both of the above two examples, then the first example above is non-conforming, while the second example is conforming.

Since Microsoft's `__declspec(align())` works with `typedef` you can just leave your code as it is if you want, and just ignore the spurious warning the compiler emits. If you want your code to be conforming then you should use `alignas(16)` and put it after the `struct` keyword. Since you probably want `tag_RECTF` to have the same alignment as `RECTF` I recommend doing the later.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that the reordering is correct, and for the suggestions.  

I see now that the alignas keyword is newly supported by VS 2015 as VS 2013 won't compile it, so we'll have to keep using __declspec(align()) until we fully make the switchover to use the new compiler for production work.  Thanks again.